# Can't find the origin of a path item on MacOS

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2

Here is my path:

> [thomas:~] $ echo $path
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin /usr/local/share/dotnet /opt/X11/bin ~/.dotnet/tools /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS /Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin

I am trying to find the origin of the first item (Python.framewok/Version/3.7/bin).

I am using iTerm2 / Zsh

The path is NOT in:

- .profile (not loaded by Zsh anyways)
- .bash_profile (not loaded by Zsh anyways)
- .zshrc
- .zprofile
- /etc/paths
- /etc/paths.d

where does it come from?